# jsf default value of Boolean in composite component

Tags: java, jsf, composite-component

I have problem, when i am passing to composite component Boolean value of property its never null.

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="bool" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false"/>
</cc:interface>

<c:if test="#{bool eq null}">NULL</c:if>
<c:if test="#{bool eq true}">true</c:if>
<c:if test="#{bool eq false}">false</c:if>
```

it never shows me null, it shows me false instead of null. 
(i am using `-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false`)

but when i passing it like that:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="bean" type="testClasses.Test" required="false"/>
</cc:interface>

<c:if test="#{bean.bool eq null}">NULL</c:if>
<c:if test="#{bean.bool eq true}">true</c:if>
<c:if test="#{bean.bool eq false}">false</c:if>
```

That work good. Whats the problem ?

Comment: `#{bool eq null}` ergo `it never shows me null, it shows me false instead of null`. The expression evaluates to a boolean, isn't that what you want?

Comment: java.lang.Boolean not the boolean. I need null for some unexpected cases.

Comment: Ok. Try this `<c:if test="${empty bool}">` or `<c:if test="#{empty bool}">` instead.